# Concatenate strings while finding distinct objects in a list in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I have a list of objects like below:

```
input = [ { "name" = "A", "security_group_id" = "sg-123456", "tcp_port" = 3306 },
          { "name" = "B", "security_group_id" = "sg-123456", "tcp_port" = 3306 },
          { "name" = "C", "security_group_id" = "sg-123456", "tcp_port" = 443 },
          { "name" = "D", "security_group_id" = "sg-567890", "tcp_port" = 22 } ]
```

I need to remove the duplicate elements from the list by `security_group_id` and `tcp_port` *but* concatenate their `name` fields together (similar to a GROUP_CONCAT in MySQL).
The desired output is:

```
output = [ { "name" = "A,B", "security_group_id" = "sg-123456", "tcp_port" = 3306 },
           { "name" = "C",   "security_group_id" = "sg-123456", "tcp_port" = 443 } ]
           { "name" = "D",   "security_group_id" = "sg-567890", "tcp_port" = 22 } ]
```

I can't use `distinct` as the objects are already distinct. Is there a way to loop over the objects and concatenate their `name` fields if the other fields in the object already exist in the list?

Comment: Where does the source for these come from. Remember terraform is not a programing language but a configuration language. while it does provide conditional expressions and some ability to use things like for loops to build dynamic configuration or filtering, its not designed for having complex logic in it. Is it possible to change the source of the data to take care of this for you?

Comment: Sadly I don't have control over the input - they are generated from the output of a module under another team's control

Comment: Ah OK maybe someone can answer it but personally I don't believe such transformation should be in your terraform code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the input objects will always have exactly these attributes then it is possible to create the effect you are hoping for, but somewhat awkward since Terraform is not designed for this sort of flexible data wrangling.

The general idea here would be to follow a similar strategy that an SQL engine might follow internally when implementing the kind of query you are imagining:

1. Project the list into a map whose keys represent all of the data you intend to group by, and whose values are lists of objects with those values.
2. Project that result again to transform each list of objects into a single object with the concatenated name you want.

```
locals {
  group_by = {
    for obj in var.input : "${obj.security_group_id}:${obj.tcp_port}" => obj...
  }
  output = tolist([
    for objs in local.group_by : {
      name              = join(",", objs[*].name)
      security_group_id = objs[0].security_group_id
      tcp_port          = objs[0].tcp_port
    }
  ])
}
```

The `...` symbol after `obj` in the first expression is what's doing most of the work here: it tells Terraform to group together all of the results which have the same key, which therefore behaves a bit like `GROUP BY security_group_id, tcp_port` in SQL.

`local.output` should then match the shape you described.

Comment: Hats off to you sir, this is a great solution which I would never have seen. Glad I keps an eye on this

Comment: One minor edit, shouldnt it be `join(",", objs[*]["name"])`?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was too hasty in submitting this before I double-checked what I wrote. I'll update the answer. Thanks!